# Espaço e cor entre ViewCell num ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Gostaria de ajuda pois não estou conseguindo deixar da maneira que espero, há espaço a mais entre as cores. O cinza é o fundo que coloquei e o amarelo está sendo preenchido pelo `Binding`. A linha vermelha é um `BoxView` que quero utilizar pra fazer a repartição entre eles. O cinza entre eles não deve aparecer.

[image: exemplo]

Segue o código:

```
    <ListView x:Name="lstLeilao" 
              ItemTapped="OnTapLance"
              HasUnevenRows="True"
              BackgroundColor="LightGray">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- DataTemplate  = exibe dados de uma coleção de objetos em um ListView -->
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding COR}"
                                     Margin="0">

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Código do Leilão: "
                                       Margin="2, 0, 2, 0"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ID_LEILAO}"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Data do Início: "
                                       Margin="2, 0, 20, 0"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DT_INICIO}"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Data do Término: "
                                       Margin="2, 0, 4, 0"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DT_TERMINO}"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Hora do Início: "
                                       Margin="2, 0, 19, 0"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding HR_INICIO}"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Hora do Término: "
                                       Margin="2, 0, 2, 0"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding HR_TERMINO}"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Produto: "
                                       Margin="2, 0, 56, 0"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding PRODUTO}" 
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Quantidade: "
                                       Margin="2, 0, 35, 0"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding QTDE}" 
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="Unidade: "
                                       Margin="2, 0, 55, 0"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding UNIDADE}" 
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       FontSize="Small"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout>
                            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" 
                                     HeightRequest="1"
                                     Margin="0"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Coloque  `SeparatorVisibility="None"` abaixo do `HasUnevenRows="true"` na sua listview e veja se resolve

Comment: Que pena, não foi, mas agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[O `StackLayout` tem um `Spacing` padrão de 6 dip](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stacklayout.spacing?view=xamarin-forms). É justamente esse espaçamento entre os itens que está aparecendo cinza na sua tela: é o espaço entre os seu stack que contém os dados paresentados e o outro stack que contém o `BoxView`.

Uma das formas de resolver é removendo o `Spacing` do `StackLayout` onde os itens em questão estão apresentando o 'problema':

```
<ViewCell>
    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding COR}"
                     Margin="0">
            <!-- um monte de outros stacks -->
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" 
                     HeightRequest="1"
                     Margin="0"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

### Dica sobre o seu layout:

Você está usando vários `StackLayout`s aninhados, algumas vezes desnecessáriamente como é o caso do `BoxView`. Quanto mais elementos você inclui (pricipalmente falando de `ListView`, que vai renderizar isso várias vezes), maior será o efeito sobre a performance do aplicativo.

**Sugiro que você [veja o vídeo e leia essas dicas sobre performance com `Xamarin.Forms`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance)**, me ajudou bastante e acredito que possa te ajudar também.

Comment: Caramba, que aula de resposta. Deu certo. Você acredita que apenas no BoxView errei em colocar StackLayout? Poxa, adoraria demais assistir ao vídeo, mas não sei praticamente nada do inglês, que vontade de chorar ahaha

Comment: @DeividSouza na própria `ViewCell` você também tem 2 `StackLayouts`. o que tem a cor de fundo já poderia zer a raiz, e o `BoxView` ficaria dentro dele (você não teria o problema do `Spacing`). Esse link que eu mencionei [está disponível em português também](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance), e no vídeo você pode configurar para exibir legendas com auto-tradução para português. A tradução não é das melhores, mas já lhe ofecere algum conhecimento mais acessível.

Comment: Ótimo. Estou lendo por essa auto-tradução mesmo ao menos pra quebrar um galho. Onde você postará o conteúdo que está traduzindo?

Comment: Pode me passar como encontro seu canal? Queria acompanhar. No texto que me passou aprendi muito mesmo quanto a layout, agradeço.

Comment: Encontrei um texto explicando exatamente referente à performance do Xamarin em português, muito bom: http://www.macoratti.net/17/01/xamforms_dicas1.htm